# Windows 7 firewall: Block all incoming requests from a certain IP

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall

How can I modify the Windows 7 firewall to block all incoming requests from a certain IP in my network?

In "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security", I can define new rules. However, none of the options in the "Inbound Rule Wizard" seems to fit (or, more likely, I just don't understand it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go through theses steps while running the wizard

1. On the first page choose `Custom` for the type of rule.
2. Click Next till you get to `Scope` and put the ip address in the `remote IP` section.
3. After that click Next to `Action` and choose `Block the connection`.
4. Click next till you get to `Name` and give the rule a name.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:

If you configure a 'blocking' rule, but also have an 'allowing' rule, the latter will override the other (see the reason [heere](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755191(v=ws.10).aspx)).

To keep the allowing rule but also block the specific IP, is necessary to change your approach, instead of creating a new rule, you just:

1. Edit the existing `Allow rule`.
2. Go to `Scope > Remote IP address`.
3. Check the `These IP addresses` radio button.
4. Click `Add`.
5. Check the `This IP address range` radio button.
6. Set the range from a lower bound to one prior to the banned IP(s).
7. Click `Accept`.
8. Repeat steps 4 to 7 but this time you set a range from after the banned IP to the upper bound.
9. Click `Accept`.